# How to send the “~” character in vbs

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

I am creating a VBScript to automatically execute my favorite DOS games through DOSBox. Since DOS only supports 8 character file names, when I try to mount the directory "C:\Users\jordanh\Documents\DOS\Roms\INDIAN~3\INDY264" the VBScript sends the enter key instead of "~3\INDY264", as in VBS "~" = {ENTER}.

Any ideas how to send the "~" character rather than enter?

Comment: Please post the line of script.

Comment: The tilde is not a reserved character is DOS or VBS.  Please provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever tried concatenation and `Chr()` function? Something like:

```
"C:\Users\jordanh\Documents\DOS\Roms\INDIAN" & Chr(126) & "\INDY264"
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks looks like that will work. I am relativley new to any BASIC based langauge, so I am always putting semi-colons at the end of each line :D.

Comment: Well, mark your question as answered when you are done with it :)

Comment: Yup, I will just got to do my homework first :D (I was at school when I replyed)

Answer (score 5):

The Chr() trick as described by S0pra will work. You can also escape the tilde and other characters (as !, + and ^) by embracing them: {~}, {!}, {+} and {^}. See also this reference: [sendkeys on ss64.com](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)

Comment: Embracing is simpler and cleaner. Character codes can be tricky to remember. This is the recommended method.